# Dictionary manipulation in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a piece of text and I have created a dictionary in python. It has words as keys, and the number of times the words has occurred in the text as values. This dictionary is sorted in decreasing value of the values field. Here is a snippet of my list:

```
[('the\n', 1644), ('and\n', 872), ('to\n', 729), ('a\n', 632), ('she\n', 541), 
('it\n', 530), ('of\n', 514), ('said\n', 462), ('i\n', 410), ('alice\n', 386),
('in\n', 369), ('you\n', 365), ('was\n', 357), ('that\n', 280), ('as\n', 263), 
('her\n', 248), ('at\n', 212), ('on\n', 193), ('all\n', 182), ('with\n', 181),
('had\n', 178), ('but\n', 170), ('for\n', 153), ('so\n', 151), ('be\n', 148), 
('not\n', 145), ('very\n', 144), ('what\n', 136), ('this\n', 134),
('they\n', 130), ('little\n', 128), ('he\n', 120), ('out\n', 117),
('is\n', 108), ... ]
```

I want to print the 25 most frequent words. that is fairly simple and I have done it. The next part is to print the 25 most frequent words starting with the letter "f". How do I find this and append it to the list of 25 most frequent words?

Also, I have to add a rank of all the words. For example, in my dictionary, "the" will be ranked 1, "and" 2 and so on. How do I add a rank to the list of words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just filter using a list comprehension:

```
f_words = [(word, freq) for (word, freq) in the_list if word.startswith('f')]
```

Since the original list is sorted, so will this one be. You can then just slice it to get the top 25: `f_words[:25]`

Comment: if i wanted to rank these documents starting from 1-25, how can i include the rank in the list of key:value pairs?

Comment: You can use `enumerate(some_list, 1)` to get (index, element) pairs. The `1` indicates the starting point, otherwise it starts counting from zero.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use `itertools.ifilter()` and `itertools.islice()`:

```
f_words = islice(ifilter(lambda x: x[0].startswith("f"), words), 25)
for word, count in f_words:
    print word.rstrip()
```

Instead of `ifilter()`, you can also use a generator expression:

```
f_words = islice((w for w, c in words if w.startswith("f")), 25)
for word in f_words:
    print word.rstrip()
```

Both these approaches have the advantage that you don't need to filter the whole list first -- the loop will stop after 25 words.